# How do I add dynamic photos to a Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi, photo, slicers

I work for a retailer and have put together a 1-page "Store Tour" report that shows physical store details, financial results, closest competitors, etc. when you select a store from the menu (slicer).

Everything works fine. You select a store, and the data populates.

The last thing I want to add in is a photo of the store. And of course, it has to be dynamic like the rest of the information.

What are my options? Or what BI add-ins do you recommend?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-images-tables

Comment: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/05/19/storing-large-images-in-power-bi-datasets/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Some of my photos load properly when I select a store, but other photos don't work. But then I try the ones that didn't work, and they start working and the ones that were working stopped working. Any ideas?